# Are Worker->Master->Worker promise based messages possible in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to communicate master and worker promise based? I want my worker to send message to master from a certain function and await response in that function. I have throughoutly explored this message based system and built several projects with it, but still it bugs me pretty well that messages are single way. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: 2 diff protocols ( msg based w events vs promises , promise resolution ) can be conjoined or wrapped . example on how to do - https://codeburst.io/promises-for-the-web-worker-9311b7831733

Comment: Thank you! So the main idea is just to wrap everything in promises and await for certain message id?

Comment: yes  messages / events are wrapped by serializer using $ID to organize the state of a list of promises . each promise wraps a message. more details in workerize-loader src -  https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader/blob/master/src/rpc-wrapper.js#L26

Comment: Yes, I got it. This way it works. Thanks a lot! ^)